# Why doesn't Bane reveal Batman's identity?

Tags: dc, comics, batman, character-motivation

In the *Knightfall* series, the following events occur:

> Bane discovers that Bruce Wayne is Batman. Bane proceeds to confront Batman and breaks his back.

Why wouldn't / didn't / hasn't Bane revealed his knowledge of Batman's secret identity?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bane, from what I gather, isn't in it for the money or fame/infamy he'd receive for outing Bruce Wayne as Batman. Quoting Wikipedia:

> His ambition turns to destroying Batman, about whom he had heard stories while an inmate. He is fascinated with Gotham City because, like the prison, it is a place where fear rules—but in Gotham, it is the fear of Batman. Bane is convinced that the demonic bat that haunted his dreams since childhood is a representation of the Batman.

He's only in it for the challenge, to rid himself of the demonic bat figure, and to take control of Gotham. He has no need to meddle with Bruce Wayne.

Comment: Bruce Wayne is just a man.  A man can be killed, a man can be broken, a man can be beaten.  Batman is not a man, Batman is a legend.  Bane wants to destroy a legend, not a man.

Comment: I feel like this answer (and subsequent comment) are combining the movies with the comics. I am asking just from a comics stand point.

Comment: @JackBNimble I was only taking a quote from a movie character to prove my point about the comics. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @JackBNimble: I think this answer accurately describes the situation in the comics too.

Comment: @JackBNimble Does Bane know Batman's identity in the comics ?

Comment: @Kalissar [Yes](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/74368/25379).

Comment: Who would want to reveal it to? I don't see him as the boastful type, nor does it further his plans.