# How many people have deduced Batman's secret identity?

Tags: dc, batman

I've seen DVK's question [How many people who weren't superheroes did Batman reveal his identity to?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32455/how-many-people-who-werent-superheroes-did-batman-reveal-his-identity-to), and I recently began playing the *Arkham City* game, and the two combined made me wonder just how many people have independently determined that Bruce Wayne is Batman.

Because I know this is a potentially gigantic list, given how many different adaptations of the Batman story there have been over the years, I'm including a few some restrictions:

1. Comics only. No video games, television shows, or movies. No restriction on eras, so if somebody figured it out in the Golden Age and the knowledge was retconned out of their brain, they still count.
2. Main continuity (of the era) only. "What If?" sort of storylines, *Elseworlds* for example, don't count. To clarify, I'm trying to discount offshoot continuities that get set up when a writer has a neat idea, but DC doesn't want to screw up the main titles. I **don't** want to limit by time period; anything as far back as the Golden Age is fine by me, as long as it fits the other criteria and even if the story in question is no longer canon
3. They can't have used super powers to figure it out, other than super intelligence; powers of deduction only. So if Superman uses his x-ray vision to peek through Batman's cowl, he doesn't count. Likewise with J'onn J'onzz reads Batman's mind
4. They must have survived at least to the end of the storyline in which they find it out. So a one-off villain who gets killed by the end of the issue (a surprisingly frequent occurrence in the Golden Age), doesn't count
5. They must be named characters. I'm mostly adding this to prevent answers like "Ra's al Ghul figured it out, so he probably told the entire League of Assassins." That may be true, but it's not really helpful

To reiterate, I'm not interested in people who Batman told. I'm only interested in people who managed to figure it out on their own, like Tim Drake.

Comment: Can you clear up "Main Continuity"?  The currently continuity only goes back to 2011.  Because of that I think the only two people who would have deduced it would be Tim Drake and Ra's al ghul but we can't be sure as the editors have put into question anything before The New 52 (as the current continuity is referred to).

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza When I say "main continuity", I mean the main continuity of any particular era: Golden Age, Silver Age, pre-/post-Crisis, whatever. I'm specifically trying to avoid offshoot continuities that get set up when a writer has a neat idea, but DC doesn't want to screw up the main titles. The *Elseworlds* series, for example. I'll edit the question to include this clarification

Comment: I only know of one. Henri Ducard, the detective who taught Batman, figured it out in Detective Comics #600, but did nothing with the information because he considered Batman to be a useful distraction from the real crime out there.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Even given the filters, there were plenty of folks who were able to deduce who Batman is by brainpower, proximity or exposure. Their advantage was not just their brain but either predispositions or occupations which lent themselves to isolate who Batman could be and the time to follow up on it.

#### People who KNOW:

**Bane:** Bane is revealed to know who Batman is simply by watching him move. He recognized the kinesthetic profile of Bruce Wayne as Batman from a rooftop during a surveillance mission. It was kinda creepy.

[image]

**R'as Al Ghul:** Immortal, time on his hands, super-intelligent and obsessed with having Batman (Bruce Wayne) succeed him. He enters the scene in Batman #232 already knowing. He appears to have always known or been reasonably sure who Batman was. He, however, isn't interested in revealing the Batman persona.

**The Riddler:** Riddles are his thing and "Who is Batman" is just one more. He doesn't reveal it because frankly his life would be empty without Batman. He also told HUSH. Rumor has it he lost the information during a coma but will likely deduce it again during a moment of boredom.

**Owlman:** A parallel reality version of Batman. In his reality Bruce Wayne was his brother so he didn't have to work too hard to make the leap to Batman's identity.

**Deathstroke:** Figured it out by deducing who Robin/Nightwing was and working backward.

**Amanda Waller:** Brilliant operational leader of the Suicide Squad, let Batman in on HER knowledge when she wanted him to work for her. She likely deduced it the way any good spy network would have, the process of elimination. The two don't get along.

**Maxwell Lord:** Pathological but brainy, Max also had access to the spy technology of Brother Eye which helped him confirm what he already suspected.

**Silver St. Cloud:** Spent so much time up-close-and-personal with Bruce's face she eventually recognized the true owner of Batman's jaw...

**Lady Shiva:** Nightwing commented that she was on the list of enemies who definitely knew, in a conversation he had with Robin III (Tim Drake) in “Gotham Knights #8.” Given her fighting mastery, I suspect she knew the same way Bane did, instinctively from watching Wayne from a distance. It is later confirmed when Bruce Wayne goes to her for retraining after his back problem.

**Lex Luthor:** In the so smart he's dumb category, Lex only recently discovers who Batman is when Dick Grayson's identity is outed. I guess knowing who Batman was just wasn't on his list of things to do while obsessing over Superman...

[image]

#### People who probably KNOW but it's not been revealed:

**Police Commissioner Gordon:** Really? This guy has been having conversations with Batman for YEARS on a rooftop by a bat-spotlight. During No Man's Land, Batman attempts to regain Gordon's trust by revealing himself, but Gordon refuses to look at him, stating that if he wanted to know Batman's identity, he could have figured it out years ago, and even cryptically saying, "And for all you know, maybe I did."  He didn't get to be the top cop of Gotham by being a complete idiot. Let's call it plausible deniability and move on, shall we?

**The Joker:** Despite his sociopathic tendencies disguised as madness, the Joker has been depicted as a genius, with a mind so convoluted, yet brilliant, he defies even the Martian Manhunter's telepathy. While it has never been officially outed, it is safe to assume HE of all people knows who Batman is.

**Hugo Strange:** A premier behavioral psychologist in the DC Universe, he has always hinted he knows who Batman is but never manages to be around when and if Batman is revealed. It would be a total failure of the writing if he DIDN'T.

**Man-Bat:** Dr. Robert Kirkland Langstrom has been to the Batcave more than once by following bats there. Unfortunately, his memory is fragmented when he is in his mutated form so the memory is probably there but unable to be accessed directly.

**Tsunetomo:** Dead. One of Bruce Wayne’s martial arts teachers. Recognized Batman’s fighting style in “Detective Comics Annual #3″.

#### People who KNEW but don't now...

**Chronos I:** David Clinton. Found out the secret IDs of Batman and several other JLAers a long time ago, according to an “Identity Crisis” retcon. Then he got mindwiped by Zatanna. Then Despero recently helped him rediscover those memories in “JLA: Crisis of Conscience.” Then they got wiped out (or suppressed, or whatever) by Zatanna all over again . . . until further notice?

**Felix Faust:** Found out the secret IDs of Batman and several other JLAers a long time ago, according to an “Identity Crisis” retcon. Then he got mindwiped by Zatanna. Then Despero recently helped him rediscover those memories in “JLA: Crisis of Conscience.”

**The Floronic Man:** Jason Woodrue. Found out the secret IDs of Batman and several other JLAers a long time ago, according to an “Identity Crisis” retcon. Then he got mindwiped by Zatanna. Then Despero recently helped him rediscover those memories in “JLA: Crisis of Conscience.”

**Matter Master:** Mark Mandrill. Found out the secret IDs of Batman and several other JLAers a long time ago, according to an “Identity Crisis” retcon. Then he got mindwiped by Zatanna. Then Despero recently helped him rediscover those memories in “JLA: Crisis of Conscience.”

**The Wizard:** William I. Zard. Found out the secret IDs of Batman and several other JLAers a long time ago, according to an “Identity Crisis” retcon. Then he got mindwiped by Zatanna. Then Despero recently helped him rediscover those memories in “JLA: Crisis of Conscience.”

**Henri Ducard:** One of Bruce’s old teachers; he deduced the secret in the “Blind Justice” story arc, which has allegedly been erased from continuity, which would certainly explain why I don’t remember ever seeing Ducard make any use of this knowledge in any subsequent appearances in other comics.

**The Wrath:** A Pre-Crisis Anti-Batman, a villain whose parents were killed by a young police officer, and decides to embark upon a path of revenge. When he and Batman meet, the two engage in a battle of wits and he learns of Batman's identity. Believed to be deceased. This is later retconned out of existence.

**Prometheus I:** A dark mirror of Batman, this supervillain's origin mirrors the Dark Knight's. Parents killed, world traveled, skills and technology acquired, he becomes what Batman could have, a super-genius mad at the world. Having defeated Batman in hand-to-hand combat and taken down the Justice League once or twice using information he acquired from Batman's computer, he ended his formidable career in a psychic loop because he was deemed "unable to be effectively incarcerated' for the rest of life in Blackgate Prison. He learned all of the Justice League's powers, identities and weaknesses (from Batman, no less).

Comment: Very thorough. I was surprised to learn that Hugo Strange isn't confirmed to know - that plot's been used at least twice in non-comic media, and I believe adapted into one of the movies

Comment: Honestly, I can't imagine he doesn't know. He may have the same blindness that Lex Luthor has...

Comment: You forgot Dick Grayson. And Alfred.

Comment: Re-reading, didn't Bruce go to Lady Shiva, as Bruce, for re-training during the KnightsEnd series? If I'm remembering that right, it would imply that Shiva *definitely* knows

Comment: Oops, she is in the wrong section. Yes, she is confirmed as knowing when he needs her help to retrain. You are correct. I will make the change...

Comment: I didn't include Alfred or Dick Grayson since they were almost in on the secret from the beginning, depending on which continuity you are drawing from -- there are so many these days, I think I'm going mad.

Comment: I may be remembering wrong but didn't The Absence, formally Una Nemo - a Gotham City socialite, know that Bruce was Batman?

Comment: Another aside, I'm more than slightly surprised by Silver St. Cloud's explanation. Not because I think it's implausible, but because Bruce/Batman has been "up close and personal" with *so many* women over the years (Catwoman, for instance, who had a very prominent post-sex panel not long ago), I'm surprised none of them figured it out the same way Silver did

Comment: It may be worth adding in the current Justice League members. Bruce revealed his identity to them all in the New 52 reboot, taking off his mask outside in broad daylight...sigh.

Comment: I think it would be a small improvement if you consolidated all the "Found out the secret IDs of Batman and several other JLAers a long time ago, according to an 'Identity Crisis' retcon. Then he got mindwiped by Zatanna. Then Despero recently helped him rediscover those memories in 'JLA: Crisis of Conscience.'"s into one group, rather than all the copy/paste.

Comment: @JasonBaker The wikipedia article on Silver St. Cloud says that "Her relationship with Bruce was initially in trouble due to his repeated disappearances. However, over time she was able to piece together the clues and eventually recognize her lover in the Batman costume. Silver confirms her suspicions by calling out to Bruce while he battled the villain Deadshot, causing him to turn and allowing Silver to recognize Batman's chin as the chin of Bruce Wayne." So she pretty much already knew before the chin confirmed.

Comment: I know it's mentioned in the original question, but such an exhaustive list seems like it should include also Tim Drake, who's whole origin story is basically that he figured it out and confronted Batman because he was getting darker.

Comment: In New 52 Batman told Joker he is a Bruce Wayne, but Joker was not interested since for him only Batman is important.

Comment: Even though he doesn't meet criteria 4, Detective Harvey Harris merits a mention.  Way back in Detective 226 he mentors a young Bruce Wayne (wearing a Robin costume).  He tricks young Bruce into giving himself away by dialing his own phone number from a list of numbers.  I had hoped that the character would turn up on ""Gotham".  He still might.

Comment: Jim Gordon knows. In _Batman: Year One_ Bruce is unmasked, undisguised, standing within arms reach, in broad daylight, not trying to conceal his identity, and Gordon's already met him in person (and had already suspected him of being Batman). Gordon uses the excuse he can't see without his glasses to imply he doesn't recognize him, but it's pretty obvious it's purely plausible deniability and he's lying through his teeth as Batman is still wanted by the police at the time, and no one who's still an active street detective has eyesight _that_ bad.

Comment: So, who *doesn't* know? :)

Answer (score 8):

Dr. Bradford Thorne/[Crime doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crime_Doctor_%28comics%29) is my favorite supervillain

[image]

Crime doctor the supervillian himself has a secret identity ie Dr. Bradford Thorne. As Dr. Bradford Thorne he has treated Batman's secret identity (ie  Bruce Wayne) from a wound on his shoulder.
Later crime doctor engages in a fight with Batman and tried to attack him with a knife that only scratched batman's suit to reveal the patch he himself applied on Bruce Wayne.

Comment: Is this panel showing Thorne deducing Batman's secret identity? If so, you should clarify the point; adding more panels or including a summary of the issue in question. Saying what issue this panel is *from* would also be a nice addition.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot one major player, Superman. He figured it out.

[image]

Comment: *They can't have used super powers to figure it out, other than super intelligence; powers of deduction only.*" - It's not clear how Superman worked it out in that frame, but the implication is that he used his superpowers, not his intellect.

Comment: @Valorum Superman and Batman knew of each other's identities a long time ago. It was by accident when both were placed in the same cabin of a cruise ship, " When a fire erupted on board, Bruce switched off the lights in an attempt to change into his Batman costume so he could save the day. Clark took the opportunity to change into Superman during the blackout. Fate played its hand and a light suddenly shown through their cabin’s window, exposing each other’s secret identity to his bunk mate." check out https://ifanboy.com/articles/dc-histories-batman-and-supermans-relationship/

Comment: @jim - Indeed, but this is a **different continuity** in which that incident didn't occur.

Answer (score 1):

There's also Timothy Drake who figured out Batman's identity by watching Dick Grayson's Robin do a certain circus flip that only the Flying Graysons could do. And through that, he figured out Batman was Bruce Wayne as he knew that Dick was his ward, and thus it was only logical that Bruce Wayne would also be Batman

Comment: Note that Drake is actually named in the question, so this answer is a bit redundant.

Comment: Whilst a nice find this is of course already mentioned in the question. However, if you were to add some evidence for this such as the appropriate comic panels it would still be an nice answer.