# Does Amanda Waller know the secret identity of Batman?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad-2016

In the post-credits scene of *Suicide Squad*, does Amanda Waller know the secret identity of Batman or is it was just a joke for the crowd?

I have read a lot of contradictory comments in this subject.

Comment: I haven't seen _Suicide Squad_ which is why this isn't an answer, but you also tagged this question with `dcau`. In _Justice League Unlimited_ episode _Ultimatum_ it's strongly implied she knew Batman's real identity (even referring to him as "rich boy" when threatening Batman and the rest of the Justice League, which takes him aback). In the final episode of JLU (_Batman Beyond_ epilogue) it is made definitively clear that she learned Batman's identity at some point during her career.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many people have deduced Batman's secret identity?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74349/how-many-people-have-deduced-batmans-secret-identity)

Answer (score 6):

If we assume she has access to the same intelligence as in other media, she has figured it out, and wants to let him know that, subtly.

In Justice League Unlimited, Amanda was a major recurring character, and in one tense exchange about some questionable activity, she says to him...

[image]

Comment: Did u watch the movie 'suicide squad'? I meant to the dc extended universe.

Comment: Did you see where I said "if we assume"? A common practice when analyzing comic book films is to look at similar stories in the other media, like comics, animation, etc, and see if it's possible if a similar solution can be applied to the medium in question.  If you want only to use the information presented in the film, then the answer to your question is "there is no way to tell" This is probably why many of the comments you've read are contradictory - they are only guesses and clever theories, as is mine.

Comment: In the movie, Wayne does speak in Batman's voice for most of the scene. I took this to mean she did know.

Comment: Hm, I can't recall if in SS Batman uses the voice distorter we heard in BvS.  I assumed he disguised his voice in a similar way