# In Knightfall, how did Bane discover Batman's identity?

Tags: dc, batman, bane

I've just finished reading the entire KnightSaga: that's Knightfall, KnightQuest and KnightsEnd. I've also read Bane's origin story (Vengence of Bane) and the various issues leading up to Knightfall; and I'm still puzzled.

Towards the end of the Knightfall storyline, Bane is reavealed to have uncovered Batman's real identity and shows up at Wayne Manor. How did he know that?

In the issues, Bane does have an obsession with Batman, but he's rarely in direct contact with him. And he doesn't even tail him. He's delegated that task to the falcon guy (named 'Bird'); and clearly Bird isn't the one to figure it out. Bird even asks Bane how he knew, to which Bane doesn't give a real explanation.

After 'Knightfall: Who Rules the Night', Bane barely appears at all in in KnightQuest and KnightsEnd. (It's possible I missed an issue or two. And some issues I got my hands on had a few pages missing.)

So, my question is, do we ever learn how Bane deduced that Bruce is Batman? If so, in what issue(s)?

Comment: No need to be salty.... Stating that should mitigate "have you read x" as the OP stated that occured, thus a bit more detail is needed. Tbf when I read that series I couldn't see where it was deduced

Comment: I feel like this question is answered in the description itself. "Bird even asks Bane how he knew, to which Bane doesn't give a real explanation" suggests that Bane deduced Batman's secret identity via the power of plot. Of course, Bane is himself a genius, so it's perfectly believable that he would be one of the few people to figure out Batman's secret identity.

Comment: Oddly enough, there seems to be a recurring theme of "he knows him by how he moves" despite no actual comic panels indicating as much.

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/74349/how-many-people-have-deduced-batmans-secret-identity

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Yeah. The more I read, the more I'm beginning to realize that Batman's identity might be the worst-kept secret in all of comic history. I mean, Superman has better luck with glasses and a spit curl than Batman has with a lead-lined hi-tech cowl.

Comment: @TusharRaj: Possibly relevant is http://kerrycallen.blogspot.com/2011/07/super-antics-2.html

Comment: Maybe he hacked Tim Drake's computer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

As I recall, Bruce Wayne is attending some sort of gala or something, and Poison Ivy mind controls all the attendants (except Bruce Wayne, who slips on a filter). Then as Bruce is pretending to be a zombie with the rest of the group, Bane observes him and says "That man is the Batman." He has studied Batman so much, that he is able to see through his "fake" persona of Bruce Wayne.

[image]

> It's **HIM.** I know him Intimately now, Bird...He cannot hide from me simply be removing his mask!

Comment: Props for pinpointing the panel. +1. But this is what I'm talking about. Bane has NOT spent any amount of time with Batman that would be considered worthy of "intimate knowledge", up to this point. Certainly not enough to single him out in a crowd through  effing binoculars.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily follow that Bane can only know Batman due to working with (against) him personally/physically. Perhaps he's seen a lot of security camera footage of Batman and knows his gait and posture super well. (Or whatever)

Comment: Nah, he knows his chin. That's how everyone identifies Bruce as Batman - they memorize his chin, and recognize it.

Comment: @Adonalsium: This was the early 90s. Batman was stealthy, and security cameras were less ubiquitous.

Comment: He's read a lot of interpretive dance literature and can read the man behind the mask based on his movements.